Single frame bool tool appearance
Everything is fine in my render except for one frame where the cutout I made using the booltool to stop the water appears as a colour blue, even though there are no keyframes or anything, any ideas? I've added the pictures below.
It happens in frame 14 exactly and there is nothing in the timeline or showing in the viewport, and if I render the frame by itself it works, it is only when I render it as an animation. Please let me know if you need anything else to help me figure it out!



